# Counting groups of files based on size

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can I simplify this?  I am trying to get the count of Excel files from a directory and subdirectories based on their size.  I have at least 10 different groupings.

```
var queryList2Only = from i in di.GetFiles("*.xls", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                                 .Where(f => f.Length <= 5120)
                     select i.Length;
if (queryList2Only.Any())
{
    dest.WriteLine("Excel File <= 5 KB");
    dest.WriteLine(queryList2Only.Count());
    dest.WriteLine("");
}

var queryList3Only = from i in di.GetFiles("*.xls", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                                 .Where(f => f.Length > 5120 && f.Length <= 10240)
                     select i.Length;
if (queryList3Only.Any())
{
    dest.WriteLine("Excel File > 5 KB and <= 10 KB");
    dest.WriteLine(queryList3Only.Count());
    dest.WriteLine("");
```

EDIT:
I need this

```
  <= 5 KB,> 5 KB and <= 10 KB,> 10 KB and <= 20 KB,> 20 KB and <= 100 KB,> 100 KB and <= 1000 KB,> 1000 KB and <=5 MB,> 5 MB and <=10 MB,> 10 MB and <=20 MB,> 20 MB and <=50 MB,> 50 MB and <=100 MB
```

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            DirectoryInfo Folder = new DirectoryInfo(textBox1.Text);
            var _logFolderPath4 = Path.Combine(textBox1.Text.Trim(), "log");
            if (Folder.Exists)

                if (!Directory.Exists(_logFolderPath4))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(_logFolderPath4);

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Material\");
            bool time = false;
            using (var dest = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(_logFolderPath4, "Excel.txt")))
            {

                    if (!time)
                    {
                        dest.WriteLine("---------------------" + DateTime.Now + "---------------------");
                        dest.WriteLine("");
                        time = true;
                    }
                    CountFiles(dest, di, @"*.txt");
            }

    }
```

Comment: Define your ranges in an array, loop over it ?

Comment: How does this relate to the repository pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need LINQ for this.  It would be more efficient for you to just loop through it.  Though Rup's solution is a great use of LINQ here.

Here's a more complete version tailored for exactly what you want to do.

```
// count it
CountFiles(dest, di, @"*.xls");

public void CountFiles(TextWriter writer, DirectoryInfo directory, string searchPattern)
{
    var counter = new FileGroupCounter
    {
        { 5,    Multiplier.K },
        { 10,   Multiplier.K },
        { 20,   Multiplier.K },
        { 100,  Multiplier.K },
        { 1000, Multiplier.K },
        { 5,    Multiplier.M },
        { 10,   Multiplier.M },
        { 20,   Multiplier.M },
        { 50,   Multiplier.M },
        { 100,  Multiplier.M },
    };

    foreach (var file in directory.EnumerateFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                         // or use GetFiles() if you're not targeting .NET 4.0
    {
        counter.CountFile(file);
    }

    foreach (var result in counter)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Excel File " + result);
        writer.WriteLine(result.Count);
        writer.WriteLine();
    }
}

// and the supporting classes
public enum Multiplier : long
{
    K = 1 << 10,
    M = 1 << 20,
    G = 1 << 30,
    T = 1 << 40,
}

public class FileGroupCounter : IEnumerable<FileGroupCounter.Result>
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<long> Limits { get { return roLimits; } }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<int> Counts { get { return roCounts; } }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Multiplier> Multipliers { get { return roMultipliers; } }

    public FileGroupCounter()
    {
        limits = new List<long>();
        counts = new List<int>();
        multipliers = new List<Multiplier>();
        roLimits= limits.AsReadOnly();
        roCounts= counts.AsReadOnly();
        roMultipliers= multipliers.AsReadOnly();
    }

    private List<long> limits;
    private List<int> counts;
    private List<Multiplier> multipliers;
    private ReadOnlyCollection<long> roLimits;
    private ReadOnlyCollection<int> roCounts;
    private ReadOnlyCollection<Multiplier> roMultipliers;

    private long CalculateLength(int index)
    {
        return limits[index] * (long)multipliers[index];
    }

    public void Add(long limit, Multiplier multiplier)
    {
        int lastIndex = limits.Count - 1;
        if (lastIndex >= 0 && limit * (long)multiplier <= CalculateLength(lastIndex))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("limit, multiplier", "must be added in increasing order");

        limits.Add(limit);
        counts.Add(0);
        multipliers.Add(multiplier);
    }

    public bool CountFile(FileInfo file)
    {
        if (file == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("file");

        for (int i = 0; i < limits.Count; i++)
        {
            if (file.Length <= CalculateLength(i))
            {
                counts[i]++;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public IEnumerator<Result> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < limits.Count; i++)
        {
            if (counts[i] > 0)
                yield return new Result(this, i);
        }
    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

    public class Result
    {
        public long Limit { get { return counter.limits[index]; } }
        public int Count { get { return counter.counts[index]; } }
        public Multiplier Multiplier { get { return counter.multipliers[index]; } }

        internal Result(FileGroupCounter counter, int index)
        {
            this.counter = counter;
            this.index = index;
        }
        private FileGroupCounter counter;
        private int index;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (index > 0)
                return String.Format("> {0} {1}B and <= {2} {3}B",
                    counter.limits[index - 1], counter.multipliers[index - 1],
                    counter.limits[index], counter.multipliers[index]);
            else
                return String.Format("<= {0} {1}B",
                    counter.limits[index], counter.multipliers[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @bala: Yes.  But you could always fall back to using `GetFiles()` if you're not using .NET 4.0.

Comment: <= 5 KB,> 5 KB and <= 10 KB,> 10 KB and <= 20 KB,> 20 KB and <= 100 KB,> 100 KB and <= 1000 KB,> 1000 KB and <=5 MB,> 5 MB and <=10 MB,> 10 MB and <=20 MB,> 20 MB and <=50 MB,> 50 MB and <=100 MB

Comment: @bala: I've added a more complete version.  Should be able to count the ranges you want.  Do with it what you will.

Comment: @Jeff:It is giving error like type or namespace readonly collection could not be found

Comment: @bala: It uses the [`ReadOnlyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) found in the `System.Collections.ObjectModel` namespace.  You'll have to include `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;` in your code.

Comment: Thanks Jeff and also  return limits[index] * (long)multipliers[index];

Comment: In this line for LIMITS it is giving error like An object reference is required for nonstatic field,method or property Form1.Filegroupcounter.Limits

Comment: @Jeff:Can you help me with this issue

Comment: @bala: You need to create an instance of the counter, these are not static properties.  You can create it the same way it is shown in my example.

Comment: @bala: I don't know how much clearer I can make it.  Everything you see in the `CountFiles()` method is all you need to be able to use the class.  Initialize the counter by assigning it to a variable and defining the limits: `var counter = new FileGroupCounter { ... };`  Call the `CountFile()` method for each file to get it counted.  Then print the results by enumerating through the counter.  If you could add in your question exactly how you declared the variables and used it, I could help you better with this.

Comment: @Jeff:Look at my edit..Other than your code this is what i have done

Comment: @bala: So you're using the method, that's fine.  You can actually copy everything I have in the code excluding the first two lines into your code file but inside your Form's class definition.  It should just work with no other changes.

Comment: Ya but it is giving error in this line return limits[index] * (long)multipliers[index]; An object reference is required for nonstatic field,method or property Form1.Filegroupcounter.Limits

Comment: @bala: Oh duh, I made a change after verifying the code which incidentally broke it.  On the `CalculateLength()` method, replace `static` with `private`.  Sorry, I should have caught that sooner when your first mentioned it.  It should work now.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have  your ranges in a collection, and enumerate over them.
Here is an example that should get you going - the sizes array contains the steps, of course you should choose the steps that makes sense to your application:

```
int[] sizes = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(n => (int)Math.Pow(2,n + 8)).ToArray();
int lower = 0;
foreach(var size in sizes)
{
    var files = di.GetFiles("*.*").Where(f => f.Length >= lower && f.Length < size);
    Console.WriteLine("Between {0} and {1} bytes:", lower,size);
    foreach(var file in files)
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}",file);
    lower = size;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think only real optimisation here would be to ensure you only call `di.GetFiles("*.xls", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)` once - since that will actually hit the filesystem rather than being lazily executed like most LINQ. Sure, the filesystem will cache the results of this but can't be slower to stay in memory and reuse the list.

Once you're in memory Jeff might be right - just count yourself - thought that doesn't seem very elegant :-) and it probably doesn't make a lot of difference here unless you're dealing with huge numbers. You just want to try and keep the number of allocations / reallocations down. With as much LINQ as I can cram in

```
var files = di.GetFiles("*.xls", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
// map to a list of numbers, 0 = up to 5K, 1 = 5-10, etc.
var sizes = files.Select(f => (f.Length / 5120));
var countsBySize = sizes.GroupBy(s => s)
                        .Select(g => new { Size = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                        .OrderBy(s => s.Size);
var results = countBySize.ToList();
```

which returns a list of 5K buckets and count of files in each bucket. If you're just going to foreach this then don't do the final ToList. If you wanted the individual files in each bucket you should group by the (f.Length / 5120) without selecting it first.

Comment: Ah grouping, another great alternative using a great use of LINQ.

Comment: @Jeff It seems a bit of a waste to group by the numbers just to then count them though. Ideally you'd just build up the buckets and counts as you work though the list (i.e. your solution).

Comment: @Rup: Oh yeah, for this case... a bit overkill if we're just counting.  But if we otherwise needed to do something with the files, this would work well.

Comment: p.s., typo: `s.Count()` -> `g.Count()`

Comment: <= 5 KB,> 5 KB and <= 10 KB,> 10 KB and <= 20 KB,> 20 KB and <= 100 KB,> 100 KB and <= 1000 KB,> 1000 KB and <=5 MB,> 5 MB and <=10 MB,> 10 MB and <=20 MB,> 20 MB and <=50 MB,> 50 MB and <=100 MB

Comment: Right - I suspect Jeff's solution where you can set the limits will work better for you then. I can't see an easy efficient way to select into those buckets here.